# How to deal with retina assets (titanium)

Tags: ios7, titanium-alloy

I have 2 sets of files:
1) Non retina images and retina images.

I am currently using the non retina images in my app. How and when do I use the retina images.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add a retina image with "@2x" to the filename and Titanium will automatically display that if the OS is retina, e.g. if your image is "example.png", add an image called "example@2x.png".

Here's a good explanation: http://fokkezb.nl/2013/09/17/smarter-image-paths/

I can't find the link to the Titanium documentation unfortunately, though I'm sure it's explained there somewhere...

EDIT: Thanks to @Dragon for [the docs link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens)

Comment: Correct Phil, [Here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens) is the docs link.

Comment: Thanks guys. If I specifically specify the file name:

backgroundImage: "images/1x/example.png"

How would it know to use 

backgroundImage: "images/2x/example@2x.png"

Comment: you don't put it in the folder /2x/ you put it in the same folder as the existing image e.g. /images/example.png and /images/example@2x.png

Comment: Thanks Phil, what I dont get is if I hardcode the path for the image in say a View. <View backgroundImage: "example.png"/>, how is titanium going to know to use backgroundImage: "example@2x.png" instead